# supple, non flabby sheaf

Tags: examples-counterexamples, sheaf-theory

Can anyone give an example of a **sheaf that is supple, but not flabby**?

Consider sheafs $\mathcal{F}$ of Abelian groups over $X$.

- it is [**flabby**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_sheaf) if for any $U$ open subset of $X$, the restriction
  $\rho_{V,U} : \mathcal{F}(U)\to\mathcal{F}(V)$ is surjective.
- It is said **supple** if, for $Z_1,Z_2$ closed in $U$ and $Z=Z_1\cup Z_2$, then any $f \in \Gamma_Z(U,\mathcal{F})$ (a section with support contained in $Z$) can be split as a sum $f_1+f_2$, with $f_i\in\Gamma_{Z_i}(U,\mathcal{F})$.

A flabby sheaf is supple, and the converse is not true, but I don't know any example... Actually I don't even know if supple is a standard notion or nomenclature.

Also, a bonus question. Take $Z_1\ldots Z_m$ closed subsets of $U$, and $Z=Z_1\cup Z_m$. Take a given sequence $f_i \in \Gamma_{Z_i}(U,\mathcal{F})$ such that $\sum f_i=0$. 
Then if $\mathcal{F}$ is flabby, we can split antissymetrically each $f_i$ as $f_i = \sum f_{ij}$ with $f_{ij} = -f_{ji} \in\Gamma_{Z_i\cap Z_j}(U,\mathcal{F})$. Is the same possible for supple sheafs?

Answer (score 1):

This was an exercise for a course I took. I transcribe my submitted solution in the following:

One example is the sheaf of Colombeau generalized functions, as described in theorem 6.2 of [Local properties of Colombeau generalized functions](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/mana.200310072/abstract) by Oberguggenberger, Pilipovic and Scarpalezos. We shall describe roughly the result here, for the one dimensional case.

For $\Omega$ an open set of $\mathbf{R}$, consider $C^\infty(M)$ the locally convex topological algebra with seminorms
$$ \| f \|_n = \sup \{ |f^k(x)| \; | \; k\le n, x\in K_n \}$$
where $\{K_n\}$ is an increasing sequence of compact sets whose union is $\Omega$, and $f^k$ denotes the $k$-th derivative of $f$.
Nets of functions $f_\epsilon \in C^\infty(\Omega)$ will be indexed by $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ and in particular, we shall deal with the class of moderate nets $\mathcal{E}(\Omega)$ and the class of null nets $\mathcal{N}(\Omega)$ given by the following.

$ \mathcal{E}(\Omega) = \{ (f_\epsilon)_\epsilon \,|\, \forall n\in\mathbf{N},
   \exists a\in\mathbf{R} \text{ s.t. }
   \|{f_\epsilon}\|_n = O(\epsilon^\alpha) \},  $

$ \mathcal{N}(\Omega) = \{ (f_\epsilon)_\epsilon \,|\, \forall n\in\mathbf{N},
   \forall a\in\mathbf{R} \text{ s.t. }
   \|{f_\epsilon}\|_n = O(\epsilon^\alpha) \},  $

That means, moderate nets are such that the $n$-norms does not diverge wildly, , and null nets are such that the $n$-norms vanish rapidly, both as $\epsilon$ goes to zero. $\mathcal{N}$ is an ideal of $\mathcal{N}$, and the Colombeau generalized functions at $\Omega$ are defined as $\mathcal{G}(\Omega) = \mathcal{E}(\Omega)/\mathcal{N}(\Omega)$.

That $\mathcal{G}$ is a sheaf is obvious.

The easiest way to see that $\mathcal{G}$ is not flabby is by taking
a counterexample. For $\Omega = (0,\infty)$, take $f_\epsilon(x) = \epsilon^{-1/x}$. Then $f = [(f_\epsilon)_\epsilon]$ is a non-zero element of $\mathcal{G}(\Omega)$ which has no lift to $\mathbf{R}$ since it diverges at the origin for any $\epsilon >0$.

To prove that it is supple, take $Z = Z_1 \cup Z_2$ with $Z_i$ closed sets in $\Omega$. Also, for $C$ a set, denote $C_\epsilon = \{x\in\Omega, d(x,C) < \epsilon\}$. Suppose that $f \in \Gamma_Z(\Omega,\mathcal{G})$, such that $f = [(f_\epsilon)_\epsilon]$. Now, we can pick a net of positive functions $\eta_\epsilon \in C^\infty(\Omega)$ such that $|\eta_\epsilon^k(x)| \le C_k\epsilon^-{p_k}$ for $x\in\Omega$ and such that

$ \eta_\epsilon(x) =
  \begin{cases}
   1 & \text{if } x \in Z_1, \\
   0 & \text{if } x \in \Omega\setminus (Z_1)_\epsilon.
  \end{cases}$

Then $g_\epsilon = f_\epsilon\eta_\epsilon$ and $h_\epsilon = f_\epsilon(1-\eta_\epsilon)$ are moderate nets, with $f_\epsilon = g_\epsilon + h_\epsilon$.
Now, $g = [(g_\epsilon)_\epsilon]$ has support in $Z_1$ since,
 for any $K$ compact in $\Omega\setminus Z_1$,
 there is a $\delta>0$ such that $K \cap (Z_1)_\epsilon = \emptyset$ for $\epsilon<\delta$,
 and hence $|g^n(x)|\sim |f^i(x)\eta^j(x)| = 0$ for $x\in K$.
 Likewise, $h = [(h_\epsilon)_\epsilon]$ has support in $Z_2$.
Hence the split $f=g+h$ is such that $g$ has support in $Z_1$ and $h$, in $Z_2$, thus proving the suppleness of $\mathcal{G}$.